# Armature completely destroys model upon moving bone

Tags: mesh, armature, bones

Good day. 
I'm completely new to Blender. And I really want to get along with it, but... it's quite more complex than I thought.

Let a example talk for me.

[image]

I made this model. A rather simple model. And I'm trying to give it an armature. I added the bones, and whatnot. However, when I set the mesh parent to the armature, and move it with Pose Mode, the armature completely obliterates the mesh.

What am I doing wrong? Could you guys please explain this to me?
I'm still quite new to Blender, but this issue happens constantly.

Update: 
**This is the .blend file of my model.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because automatic weights not always works good. Sometimes, especially if you have multi-part mesh you need to edit vertex groups manually:

[image]

until more suitable result

[image]

Comment: Could you please elaborate? As I said, I'm quite new to Blender.

Comment: Nevermind, I solved the problem by deleting all vertex points, reassigning them again, and changing my pivot point. But thanks anyways for the useful tip about weights!